# Separation of a list of color RGB tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a long list of RGB values which I assume are tuples. I want to access each R, G, B values of the tuples separately. So I can convert them to c,m,y,k with a simple operation. Thank you.

My code: (EDITED)

```
rgb = [(255,0,255), (55,0,55), (34,33,87)]
c,m,y,k = ([] for i in range(4))

for item in rgb:
    cyan = zip(*rgb)[0]
    mag = zip(*rgb)[1]
    yellow = zip(*rgb)[2]
    # of course the above zip operations return a non-iterable error


    c.append(cyan)
    m.append(mag)
    y.append(yellow)
```

Comment: `rgb_list` is a tuple of tuples of rgb values inside a list. To make it a list of tuples remove the outer `()` i.e. `rgb_list = [(255,0,255), (55,0,55), (34,33,87)]`

Comment: use `print()` to check every element of your code. If yoi get error then why didn't you put it in question - don't expect that we will run code to see error.

Comment: `rgb_list` is not a list of tuples, it's a list containing a single tuple containing three tuples. Also, there's a syntax error on the second line.

Comment: Is this the actual code that you've run? There are several issues with it that have nothing to do with your non-iterable error. You don't close parenthesis when initializing `c,m,y,k` and you reference a non-existing `rgb` variable in the loop.

Comment: what is `rgb` in your code?

Comment: Your code seems to not be at all workable. It has syntax errors, non existent variables. It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. You could just iterate straight over the list (assuming outer tuple removed) and read each rgb value and convert to cmyk.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, sorry I mixed up a variable in my code so now it is fixed and the list of tuples has been corrected. Sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have list

```
rgb_list = [((255,0,255), (55,0,55), (34,33,87))]
```

then you need only

```
for r, g, b in rgb_list[0]:
    print('r/g/b:', r, g, b)
```

result:

```
r/g/b: 255 0 255
r/g/b: 55 0 55
r/g/b: 34 33 87
```

If you need to create lists with only reds, greens, blues

```
all_reds, all_greens, all_blues = list(zip(*rgb_list[0]))
print('reds:', all_reds)
print('greens:', all_greens)
print('blues:', all_blues)
```

result:

```
reds: (255, 55, 34)
greens: (0, 0, 33)
blues: (255, 55, 87)
```